# Singular words that imply groups

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, pronominal-agreement

For example "party"(as a group of people) and "company".

"The company is fine."

But then I've seen people referring to company as "their".

Which it's correct?

"This company is fine, therefor I'll join them". Is this grammatical correct? Or should be "it"?

Comment: These are called "uncountable nouns" or "generic nouns." https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns

Comment: American English or British English?

Comment: So it would be fine to use it and then switch to their?

Comment: party and people are not uncountable nouns. uncountable nouns are: money, milk and moose poo. (attempt at alliterative joke). That said, when referring to a company, in British or American English, I'll join them is merely changing horses in mid-stream. After all, companies are made up of people. In a spoken comment, it's fine. People talk like that. It depends on the utterance (and let's not confuse this with the use of a plural verb as used in BrE like this: The party [political party] were pleased with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's okay to switch from "party" to "company" depends on what you mean by these two words.  It sounds as if you're using "party" as a group of people gathering together socially, and then switching to "company" as a noun meaning a business enterprise, since you want to use "it".  That's not fine.

"company" can mean being with one or more people socially, as in "I enjoyed your company" or "I enjoyed their company."  Used in that sense, you don't "join the company," which suggests taking a job.

Look up these two uses in the dictionary and find these meanings.